# Azure Media Service Getting Error after Stopping the Encoder and Streaming end Point

Tags: azure-media-services

I am getting the following error when i am trying to restart the Streaming end Point & Encoder after i stopped it.

A network error caused the video download to fail part-way. Please check your network connection or try again later.

I have stopped the Streaming end point and encoder after successfully testing it out to save on the billing cost.

Now when i am restarting the streaming end point and encoder i am getting the error.

I am using the publish URL to play back the content.

This happens every time i stop the streaming end point & the encoder.

Does this mean that to avoid that error i have re-encode or leave them running and incur the bill?

Answer (score 0):

When you encode or stop a program your data stored in storage and doesn't get deleted or modified with stopping the encoder or streaming-endpoint.

When you restart streaming-endpoint you can stream your content with the previously published URL. There are couple of details you need to account when you stop/start streaming-endpoints;

1. Stopping streaming-endpoint will delete DNS entries. When you restart, it might take 5-10 minutes to repopulate the deployment and DNS entries.
2. If you stop and restart, previously enabled streaming units will be deleted. If you are using Dynamic packaging feature to produce HLS and MPGEG-DASH or trying to stream live archive you need at least 1 streaming unit. Please make sure to scale to at least 1 streaming unit after you restart your streaming-endpoint.

Thanks,
Cenk